# Is it possible to double-fork a process in Java?

Tags: java, linux, fork, daemon

I need to double-fork vmware so it doesn't inherit the terminal ID (TTY/pts).

This is what I have so far, but I can't get access to the `runtime.exec` process to fork another process (which removes the terminal ID).

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("vmware");
```

Is there a way to "daemonize" in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to write a small C or C++ program to do the extra fork, setsid, all that stuff.

Comment: +1 - and note that the reason that Java does not support this explicitly is that the relevant concepts are operating system specific.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way.

Comment: Shell script, perl, python etc, would also do.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier with this, you essentially need to disconnect the application from the shell by closing the input / output streams that are implicitly connected to the current terminal.

To make this simpler fro yourself, have a look at the [akuma](https://akuma.dev.java.net/) project. This would be a cleaner solution in plain Java without any need for C wrappers.

Here is a [blog post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/01/31/writing-unix-daemon-java-akuma) discussing it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to "double fork" in order to do this, only a single fork is necessary. Then the child should close stdin, out, error and start a new session.