# Background process in linux

Tags: java, linux, sockets, process

I have developed a Java socket server connection which is working fine.

When started from a terminal, it starts from listening from client. But when I close the terminal it stops listening.

I need to continue even though the terminal closed by user from where jar file was started.

How can I run Java server socket application in Linux as background process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151214/is-it-possible-to-double-fork-a-process-in-java

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are several ways you can achieve such a thing:

1. `nohup java -server myApplication.jar > /log.txt` - this is pretty straight forward. It will just put the application in the background. This will work but it's just not a very good way to do so.
2. Use a shell wrapper and the above OR [daemon](http://www.libslack.org/daemon/) app. This approach is used by many open source projects and it's quite good for most of the scenarios. Additionally it can be included in `init.d` and required run level with regular start, stop and status commands. I can provide an example if needed.
3. Build your own daemon server using either [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/) or [Apache Jakarta Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/). Again - both are extremely popular, well tested and reliable. And available for both Linux and Windows! The one from Apache Commons is used by Tomcat server! Additionally there is [Akuma](http://akuma.kohsuke.org/).

Personally I would go with solution 2 or 3 if you need to use this server in the future and/or distribute it to clients, end users, etc. `nohup` is good if you need to run something and have no time to develop more complex solution for the problem.

Ad 2:

The best scripts, used by many projects, can be found [here](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/7.htm).

For Debian/Ubuntu one can use a very simple script based on `start-stop-daemon`. If in doubt there is `/etc/init.d/skeleton` one can modify.

```
#!/bin/sh

DESC="Description"
NAME=YOUR_NAME
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
RUN_AS=USER_TO_RUN
COMMAND=/usr/bin/java -- -jar YOUR_JAR

d_start() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $RUN_AS --exec $COMMAND
}

d_stop() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]
        then rm $PIDFILE
    fi
}

case $1 in
    start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
    d_start
    echo "."
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
    d_stop
    echo "."
    ;;
    restart)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: $NAME"
    d_stop
    sleep 1
    d_start
    echo "."
    ;;
    *)
    echo "usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Rzanek Thanks for Answer. I want to go with option 2. If you can provide me an example.

Answer (score 6):

There's one crucial thing you need to do after adding a `&` at the end of the command. The process is still linked to the terminal. You need to run `disown` after running the java command.

```
java -jar yourApp.jar > log.txt &
disown
```

Now, you can close the terminal.

Comment: that command didn't work for me i needed `java -jar yourApp.jar > log.txt &` using ubuntu, not `&` at end

Answer (score 3):

The key phrase you need here is "daemonizing a process". Ever wondered why system server processes often end in 'd' on Linux / Unix? The 'd' stands for "daemon", for historical reasons.

So, the process of detaching and becoming a true server process is called "daemonization".

It's completely general, and not limited to just Java processes.

There are several tasks that you need to do in order to become a truly independent daemon process. They're listed on the Wikipedia page.

The two main things you need to worry about are:

- Detach from parent process
- Detach from the tty that created the process

If you google the phrase "daemonizing a process", you'll find a bunch of ways to accomplish this, and some more detail as to why it's necessary.

Most people would just use a little shell script to start up the java process, and then finish the java command with an '&' to start up in background mode. Then, when the startup script process exits, the java process is still running and will be detached from the now-dead script process.

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
 java -jar yourApp.jar &
```

`&` will start new process thread,I have not tested this, but if still it not works then twite it in script file and start i with `&`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting & at the end of the command line?
For example:

```
java -jar mySocketApp.jar &
```

You can also use **bg** and **fg** commands to send a process to background and foreground. You can pause the running process by *CTRL+Z*.

Check it out this article: http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-processes.html

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**

To create new screen

```
screen -RD screenname
```

**Step 2.**

To enter into screen terminal

`press Enter`

**Step 3.**

Run your command or script (to run in the background) in the newly opened terminal

**Step 4.**

To come out of screen terminal

`ctrl + A + D`

**Step 5.**

To list screen terminals

```
screen -ls
```

that will print something like below

`There is a screen on:
        994.screenname (12/10/2018 09:24:31 AM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-contact.`

**Step 6.**

To login to the background process

```
screen -rd 994.screenname
```

Answer (score 0):

for quite terminal and this process still working background. for me, the simple and fast way to run the process in the background is using the `&!` at end of the command:

- if this app is built for X server: (eg: Firefox,Zathura,Gimp...)

```sh
$ java -jar yourApp.jar &!
```

- if this app is cli (work on the terminal)

```sh
# st is my terminal like kitty alacritty
$ st -e bash -c "lookatme --style one-dark --one $1" &!
```